# How to pass id from webpage and use to sql query?

Tags: python, flask

i've like:

```
from datetime import datetime    
import pypyodbc         
from flask import render_template, redirect, request    
   
# creating connection Object which will contain SQL Server Connection    
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=ipserver;Database=test;uid=test;pwd=asdwf')   
    
cursor = connection.cursor()    
cursor.execute("SELECT CreditoResiduo FROM SCards WHERE BarCode=??")    
s = "<table style='border:1px solid red'>"    
for row in cursor:    
    s = s + "<tr>"    
for x in row:    
    s = s + "<td>" + str(x) + "</td>"    
s = s + "</tr>"    
connection.close()    
   
@app.route('/')    
@app.route('/home')    
def home():    
    
    return "<html><body>" + s + "</body></html>"
```

The customer go to website like test.com/home/id=1 , i want pass the id to BarCode for select the proper card. How can do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets <> on the URL - where route is defined. this input will go into your function as an argument.
for example in your code:

```
@app.route('/home/<id>')    
def home(id):
    #now use id as a regular parameter
    return id
```